# Strange behaviour with double.TryParse method

Tags: double, type-conversion, tryparse

I have a very strange behaviour with the double.TryParse() method.

I have this

```
double result= -1;
bool ok;
ok = double.TryParse("0,28", out result); // ok=true, result=0.28000000000000003
ok = double.TryParse("0,52", out result); // ok=true, result=0.52000000000000002
ok = double.TryParse("0,44", out result); // ok=true, result=0.44
```

The CurrentCulture is French, I also tried specifying InvariantCulture, and this didn't solve anything.

I tried the same code in another project, and here it worked well (both WebSite in .NET 4.0). I don't know what is wrong in my project, no special references added, web.config pretty clean ... Any idea ?

Comment: What's wrong with this? Neither `0.28` nor `0.52` can be represented exactly, so you get the next closest thing.

Comment: Ok, but in this case, why this works in another project ? Myabe I should use a float instead ? With a float parsing, i have the same behaviour.

Comment: I tried with a decimal and it works, I saw that decimal stores the real value and not binary approximation. But isn't decimal too heavy for a small number like those ones ?

Comment: I have no idea why it worked in the other project. If you need precise representation of decimals, you need to use `decimal`, because these numbers use 10, not 2, as the base for the representation. The magnitude of the number itself does not matter, only the base: you cannot store `52/100` in a `double`/`float` for the same reason why you can't write `1/3` in a decimal fraction without losing some precision.

Comment: allright, so I'll use decimal ! Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome! P.S. It does not look like the question is going to get an answer, so you may want to delete it from the system.

Comment: You're right, but I'd like to know why it works on others machines and even on mine in other projects ...